# Why is my Get requests not working in express?

Tags: express, get, request

I am working in node.js with express. All Post requests works great, but Get requests is not working at all. Nothing happens.

Any idea what could be the problem is much appreciated.

This is how it looks:

```
    require('dotenv').config()
    const express = require('express');
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
    const app = express();
    const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
    
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.use(cookieParser())
    
// Get dont work:
    app.get('/api/hello', (req, res) => {
      console.log("Hello world")
      res.send('hello world')
    })

//But post works:
app.post('/api/hello', (req, res) => {
console.log("Hello world")
res.send('hello world')
})
```

I have also tried changing `/api/hello` to the full url instead of /api, which should be:
http://localhost:3000/hello, and I also tried http://localhost:3000/api/hello
But the Get request is still not working. Nothing happens when I visit the url.

**Update** (still need help):
It seems like if I change the port to 3000 (`const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;`), and I remove "/api" in the request so it just says `app.get('/hello'`, it works for get request, but then the post requests wont work. Any idea why this is?

I have a proxy in the package.json file for the frontend (React) that says: `"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"`

Comment: *Nothing happens* can you be more clear. What URL are you trying to GET from as there is no get for /api/resetPass?

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the question to be more specific. Also edited both to /hello, to make things more easy to follow.